# Microsoft Graph API calls for some functionalities

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I am using Sharepoint Office 365, but am new to Microsoft Graph APIs. I have 2 functionalities, namely create a folder at a specific location and upload a file at that location.
Suppose, the site url is:
'https://abcdef.sharepoint.com/sites/folder1/folder2'

So, first I have to create directory /folder1/folder2 inside sites, and then, need to upload a file (maybe text.txt) inside folder2.
I just need the subsequent Graph API calls which are needed to achieve the required functionality.

Note: I don't need any code structure, just the API calls required (in sequence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this steps:

1. Create folder1.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site id}/drive/root/children

{
    "name": "folder1",
    "folder": {},
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename"
}
```

2. Create a subfolder folder2 in folder1.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site id}/drive/items/{folder1 item id}/children

{
    "name": "folder2",
    "folder": {},
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename"
}
```

3. Upload a file to folder2.

```
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site id}/drive/items/{folder2 item id}:/file.txt:/content
Content-Type: text/plain

The contents of the file goes here.
```

Refer to: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJO8n.png)

Comment: If suppose my folder1 was already present at its location (/sites/folder1), and I hit the first request again, will it create a new folder, or rename the existing one, or do nothing ?

Comment: @SagnikChatterjee It will not rename the existing folder, but will create a new folder, this new folder will be named: **folder1 1**.